# Base reference not getting added

Tags: c#, reference

I have a Interface in Lib1. I've inherited it in a usercontol in lib2.

When I use that usercontrol in other soluton then I get a error saying

`The type 'lib1.IColor' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly lib1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

//in Library1

```
public interface IColor
{
string color{get;set;}
}
```

//in Library2

```
public class MyControl:UserControl,IColor
{
public MyControl()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
public string color{get;set;}
}
```

My question is why is the reference to base library(lib1) not getting added by default when I add lib2?

Comment: Do you mean, when you use the Library2 in other solution? The IDE tells you to add the Library1 as a reference in your project too?  It sounds logical if it is, because you use Library1 in your Library2 project.

Comment: my doubt was, IDE should add by default instead of me adding manually all those.

Comment: Why should it? How would it decide which dependent assemblies to add references to? How would it determine the location of the assembly - is it in the GAC or some arbitrary folder? How would it handle versioning? It is your responsibility to ensure your project has the correct reference, not the IDE's

Comment: Why it should not? It can get all the depedency assemblies from the assemblies that project has got referenced. It can get from GAC or any other folder dependending on how the references are added to that project. Its my responsibility to see that all the referenced files are in proper place.

Comment: So should it scan the entire hard drive for the depdendent assembly? What if it finds multiple versions of the assembly in different locations? What if the reference should be a project reference instead of an assembly? What if the dependent assembly has further dependencies, should it add dependencies recursively? If so how deep should it go? It's too ambiguous to automate... perhaps you could try looking into a package manager such as NuGet...

Comment: What MattDavey said, is correct, you are responsible of what assembly will be use in the execution of  your application and not the application itself *alone*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a type from a different assembly you should add a reference to this assembly. Also if you're referring to something that returns IColor you should also have a reference to lib a as the type is contained in that assembly.

Comment: my doubt was, IDE should add by default instead of me adding manually all those

Comment: There are tools (for example resharper) who can help you with this but no references are added automatically.